# NetBeans adding javax.swing and listeners triggers error

Tags: swing, class, netbeans, actionlistener, program-entry-point

Hello I know this question was here uncountable many times, but I didn't find case similar to mine. I'm making program in Java and while creating my swing main class GUI (LibraryApp) an error while compilation occoured I can't understand:

**Error: Could not find or load main class libraryApp.LibraryApp Java Result: 1**

My program contains separated jPanel classes, which contains swing elements with events for diferent functionalities and then I copy them into jTabbedPane in my main GUI class, which contains main function. I tried remake my project again and create same packages and copy *.java files on same place (except main class i recreated), same as libraries I'm using in my project.

- IDE im using is NetBeans 7.2.1
- My Project contains only one function
  main (in class LibraryApp)
- I have setuped all *.jar files in my classpath and also defined my main class (libraryApp.LibraryApp)
- I deleted cache and used "Clean and build", but I was able add
  just one more event.
- I reinstalled NetBeans, but it still didn't help my problem with main method.

Thing I found out is - after adding some number of swing components or adding more event listeners for swing components and saving file this error appears. After deleting them is all back to normal. It looks like I can have in my program just some limited number of swing components or event listeners.

I didn't try Eclipse IDE yet (my problem with Eclipse is it doesn't have Swing palette...). What can I do about this error?

**Here is my main class:**

```
package libraryApp;


// + import DEFINITIONS



public class LibraryApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {</code>


// + OBJECT DEFINITIONS

// + GLOBAL VARIABLES


    public LibraryApp() {
        initComponents();


    // + init METHODS FOR TABS

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

    // function content
    }


    // ActionListeners...



    // .. MAIN FUNCTION:

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KniznicaApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KniznicaApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KniznicaApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KniznicaApp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KniznicaApp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



    // ...FUNCTIONS WORKING WITH MAIN GUI

    // ...AND VARIABLE DEFINITIONS

}
```